# Bewildering behavior of `substitute` in R

Tags: function, r, eval, substitution, quote

Guys, this drives me crazy.

This works as expected:

```
eobj <- substitute(obj <- list(a, b), list(a = 32, b = 33))
eval(eobj)
obj
[[1]]
[1] 32

[[2]]
[1] 33
```

Now, try this:

```
efun <- substitute(fun <- function() a+ b, list(a = 32, b = 33))
str(efun)
# language fun <- function() 32 + 33  
eval(efun)
fun
# function() a+ b
```

What is going on here? How on earth `eval` gets it hands on the original form of the expression?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cause when you print `fun` it's actually print source of function (see `attributes(fun)`) which isn't modify by `substitute`.

Notice that when you define `a` or `b` in global workspace function result are the same.

You can see actual code of function by `body(fun)`.

Or compare:

```
print.function(fun, useSource=FALSE)
# function () 
# 32 + 33
print.function(fun, useSource=TRUE) # Which is default
# function() a+ b
```

Comment: Yap, it's the source indeed. But, I am still confused, were does the source come from? The source of fun is kept separate from the object itself? Expression `efun` does not have any reference to the source. `eval` does not have a direct access to the original definition.

Comment: I suppose that source is set before `substitute` works. That is `function` creates object of type expression (language?) with argument source and then substitute replace values of `a` and `b` within an expression with proper values left source untouched.

Comment: `attr(fun, "source")` shows the source that its keeping around for your function and what `print` actually prints out.  If there is no `"source"` attribute then `print` will show the actual function.  Thus `attr(fun, "source") <- NULL` will cause `print` to show the actual function rather than the contents of the `"source"` attribute.  Also `options(keep.source = FALSE)` can be used to turn off this behavior entirely in which case your functions won't get a `"source"` attribute in the first place.

Comment: @Marek It looks like that. But that means the source is set before the function is assigned to `fun`, at parsing. And where is it stored in the meantime? `efun` does not have a source attribute. This probably we best ask the R core.

Comment: @VitoshKa It's somewhere there, if you do `save(efun, file="test.txt", ascii=TRUE)` and check this file then you'll see there is original code with `a` and `b`.